# Adding MenuBar to the Portal Page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to display a MenuBar on the Liferay Portal Page (A menuBar which will be common to all portlets in that page)

For this, I have created  a custom Theme, and modified the `navigation.vm` file under the templates folder.

I have added this below MenuBar code inside the `navigation.vm` file and deployed it to the server

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Menu Bar Using CSS</title>

<style>
.menu ul
{
list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li
{
display: inline;
}

.menu ul li a
{
/*Increase Clickable Area*/
padding: 8px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;

/*Remove the Underline for the Link*/
text-decoration: none;

color: #000;
background: #ccc;
}

/*On Mouse Over the Link*/
.menu ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background: #000;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="menu">

<ul>

<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have put all these code under the `navigation.vm` file under my Applied Custom Theme, but it didn't worked (I mean the Menu Bar is not shown on the Portal page)

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `navigation.vm` does not contain `<html>`,`<head>` and `<body>` tags, these go inside the `portal_normal.vm` or if the page is a pop-up then `portal_pop_up.vm`. This file (`navigation.vm`) just helps in displaying the pages and is included inside the `portal_normal.vm` file.
2. So try moving your code inside `portal_normal.vm` for the menu-bar.

Hope this helps.